# Find and copy a row in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

**Sheet 1**

There are items in columns A - F. How do I use VLOOKUP to find a row and copy it to Sheet 2 when it matches criteria in column F?

This is the formula in a cell on Sheet 2: =VLOOKUP(apple,Sheet1!A:F, 2, FALSE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using VLOOKUP() the lookupvalue must be found in the first column of the lookuprange. If that is not the case, you can either use a combination of INDEX() and MATCH()

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:F, match("apple", Sheet1!F:F, 0))
```

or 'virtually' rearrange the layout of the table (on Sheet 1) so that the column where the match is to be expected (e.g. column F), is the first column.

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("apple", {Sheet1!F:F, Sheet1!A:F}, {2,3,4,5,6,7}, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Yerpassaur.

Comment: How come the same =INDEX formula doesn't work in Excel?

Comment: I don't use Excel so I can't comment on that. :-|